# Return values from a controller to a HTML file in Spring Boot

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, model-view-controller, web-applications

I'm currently having two problems with code:
First the values that I enter in the input from the HTML go to the controller and get calculated but, I can't get them back to the HTML so it get shown in the Chart.js chart.
The second but less problematic problem is that I also only could make it work that the calculation is done in the controller and not in the service class.

HTML-File

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Simulation-Epidemie</title>

    <!-- Referierte Libaries für individuellen Font -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800&display=swap"
          rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Link zur CDN für Graphen -->
    <script
            src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js">
    </script>

    <!-- CSS für Style der Webseite -->
    <style>

        body {
            font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
            background-color: gainsboro;
            padding-left: 100px;
            padding-right: 100px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .header-image {
            width: 100%;
        }

        .headline {
            color: blue;
            text-align: center;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .image-container {
            background-color: grey;
            padding: 5px;
        }

        .body-text {
            background-color: lightslategrey;
            width: 1200px;
            margin: auto;
            text-align: center;

        }

        .simulation {
            background-color: lightslategrey;
            width: 1200px;
            margin: auto;
            margin-bottom: 50px;
            text-align: center;

        }

        footer {
            font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 3px;
            background-color: lightblue;
            color: black;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<!-- Body seperiert in verschiedene Container zur besseren Übersicht und Funktionalität -->
<body>
<!-- Banner an der oberen Seite der Webseite -->
<div class="image-container">
    <img class="header-image" src="https://i.ibb.co/hVsJ6hq/Banner.png" alt="">
</div>

<!-- Überschrift für den Body -->
<h1 class="headline">
    <br>Simulation einer Epidemie
</h1>

<!-- Text zur Erklärung der Simulation -->
<div class="body-text">
    <br> Die Webseite dient zur Simulation und Einschätzung von Epidemien, bezogen auf einer infektionellen Krankheit
    wie z.B. Viren.
    <br>
    <br> Bitte geben Sie in den folgenden Feldern die entsprechenden Daten für die Simulation ein.

    <br><br><br>
    <!-- Inputs für die Übergabe der eingegebenen als Post an den Controller -->
    <form action="eingabe" method="post">
        <label for="Population">Größe der Population: </label>
        <input type="number" name="N"/> <br/>

        <label for="Infektionsrate">Infektionsrate durch Virus: </label>
        <input type="number" name="beta" placeholder=" " step="0.01" min="0" max="1"/> <br/>

        <!--  <label for="Tage">Laufzeitdauer: </label>
          <input type="number" name="time"/> <br/> -->

          <!-- Submit-Button zur Bestätigung der Eingaben -->
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        <br><br><br>


    </form>

</div>

<div style="width:800px; margin:0 auto;" class="Simulation">
    <br><br><br>
    <!-- Canvas-tag zur Initialisierung einer Grafik, in dem Fall des Graphen -->
    <canvas id="graph" style="width:100%;max-width:600px"></canvas>
    <script>
        //Übergebene Daten für die X- und Y-Achse
        var xValues = [50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150];
        var yValues = fetch("data.json");


        //Erstellung eines neuen Graphen
        new Chart("graph", {
            type: "line",
            data: {
                labels: xValues,
                datasets: [{
                    fill: false,
                    lineTension: 0,
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,255,1.0)",
                    borderColor: "rgba(0,0,255,0.1)",
                    data: yValues
                }]
            },
            //Einstellungen für den Graphen für Titel, Achsen-Titel, Tickrate und Farben
            options: {
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Ergebniss Epidemie-Simulation:'
                },
                legend: {display: false,},
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {min: 6, max: 16},
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'Infizierte'
                        }
                    }],
                    xAxes: [{
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'Tage'
                        }
                    }]
                }

            }
        });
    </script>
    <br><br><br>

</div>

<footer>
    <p>Entwickler: <br>
        Projekt: Web-Anwendung</p>
</footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Controller with calculation:

```
package com.example.testepi3.contorller.contorller;


import com.example.testepi3.model.EpidemieM;
import com.example.testepi3.service.EpidemieMService;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;


import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Controller

public class IndexController {
    // This method handles HTTP GET requests for the index page and returns the "index" view.
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }

    // This method handles HTTP POST requests for simulating an epidemic using the input parameters, and returns the "index" view.
    @PostMapping("/eingabe")
    public String simulateEpidemic(@ModelAttribute EpidemieM epidemic) {

        List<Integer> S = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Double> I = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Double> R = new ArrayList<>();
        double[][] result = new double[3][epidemic.getTime() + 1];


        I.add(epidemic.getN()*epidemic.getBeta());
        R.add(0.0);
        S.add((int) (epidemic.getN()-epidemic.getN()*epidemic.getBeta()));

        for (int i = 1; i < epidemic.getTime(); i++) {
            double dS = (epidemic.getBeta() * S.get(i - 1) * I.get(i - 1) / epidemic.getN());
            double newS = (S.get(i - 1) - dS);
            double newI = (I.get(i - 1) + dS - epidemic.getGamma() * I.get(i - 1));
            double newR = (R.get(i - 1) + epidemic.getGamma() * I.get(i - 1));
            S.add((int) newS);
            I.add((newI));
            R.add(newR);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < epidemic.getTime(); i++) {
            System.out.println("BevÃ¶lkerung: " + S.get(i) + "\n");
            System.out.println("Infiziert: " +I.get(i)  + "\n");
            System.out.println("Genesen: " + R.get(i) + "\n");

        }



        // Return the "index" view.
        return "index";




}}
```

Model with attributes:

```
package com.example.testepi3.model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class EpidemieM {
    // The number of times to simulate the epidemic (default value: 24).
    private int time = 24;
    // The size of the population.
    private int N;
    // The infection rate.
    private double beta;
    // The recovery time (in days).
    private double gamma = 0.14;
    // The number of susceptible individuals at each time step.
    List<Integer> S;
    // The number of infected individuals at each time step.
    List<Double> I;
    // The number of recovered individuals at each time step.
    List<Double> R ;


    // Getter and setter methods for the properties.
    public int getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(int time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public int getN() {
        return N;
    }

    public void setN(int n) {
        N = n;
    }

    public double getBeta() {
        return beta;
    }

    public void setBeta(double beta) {
        this.beta = beta;
    }

    public double getGamma() {
        return gamma;
    }

    public void setGamma(double gamma) {
        this.gamma = gamma;
    }

    public List<Integer> getS() {
        return S;
    }

    public void setS(List<Integer> s) {
        S = s;
    }

    public List<Double> getI() {
        return I;
    }

    public void setI(List<Double> i) {
        I = i;
    }

    public List<Double> getR() {
        return R;
    }

    public void setR(List<Double> r) {
        R = r;
    }

    // This method returns a string representation of the EpidemieM object.
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "EpidemieM{" +
                "time=" + time +
                ", N=" + N +
                ", beta=" + beta +
                ", gamma=" + gamma +
                ", S=" + S +
                ", I=" + I +
                ", R=" + R +
                '}';
    }
}
```

The code should calculate the course of a epidemic and show the results in a Chart.js graph.
Can someone help me?

Comment: There are two parts to this: (1) return the collection of epidemic values, and (2) render in a Chart.js graph.  The first one is the service; the second one is clearly part of the UI.  You need something that calls the service, gets the collection of epidemic values back as JSON that's parsed and loaded into the Chart.js template.  I'd have the Spring Boot service return a ResponseEntity<List<Epidemic>>.  Your client can indicate that it wants application/json in the HTTP header when it makes the GET request for data.

Comment: Take care of java naming conventions. Variable names should start with lower case character